# control for "slide to unlock" -type use-cases

Tags: android

is there an Android control for getting the user to slide something on the screen?  Here's a mockup of the kind of widget I am looking for, in two states:

[image: UI slider]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single widget built into Android for that, sorry. The closest would be `SlidingDrawer`, and that's not all that close to what you have in mind, I think.

Comment: As an update note that SlidingDrawer is deprecated since API level 17